# PowerShell equivalent of BASH (etc) 'type' command?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, powershell-2.0, command-line-interface

On *nix, using BASH (etc) you ask the system where a command is located (etc) by using the 'type' shell built-in like this:

```
$ type cat
cat is /bin/cat
```

Is there an equivalent of this 'type' command in Microsoft PowerShell 2.0 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An equivalent is `Get-Command`.

```
PS C:\> Get-Command ls

CommandType     Name       Definition
-----------     ----       ----------
Alias           ls         Get-ChildItem
Application     ls.exe     D:\usr\local\wbin\ls.exe
Application     ls.exe     C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ls.exe
```

**Windows 10 Update:**

Since I've posted this answer, it appears that the behavior of `Get-Command` has changed. To include all results (in the style of Un*x) `type`), now I need to pass the `-All` flag, like so:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command -All ls

CommandType     Name                 Version    Source
-----------     ----                 -------    ------
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
Application     ls.exe               0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\ls.exe
```

As noted in a comment, this *doesn't* include the `Definition` column as was the previous behavior. I can't determine a command-line argument to add the definition column, but as noted by @voutasaurus in the comment below, one can use:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Command -All ls).Definition
Get-ChildItem
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\ls.exe
```

Version information for reference (I odn't have the version information associated with the original answer text, but I'm guessing that it was Windows 7):

```
PS C:\> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      15063  0
```

Comment: This doesn't work for functions defined in $profile, whereas type returns the definition of the function in bash.

Comment: I'm getting this:

    > Get-Command Get-Command
    
    CommandType     Name                                               Version    
Source
    -----------     ----                                               -------    ------
    Cmdlet          Get-Command                                        3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core

If you use (Get-Command Get-Command).Definition then you actually get the definition.

Comment: Thanks @voutasaurus that must have changed since the answer was posted. I've amended the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Get-Command has a -ShowCommandInfo parameter that does this. It also works for functions defined in $profile :

```
PS C:\Users\vp937ll> Get-Command l -ShowCommandInfo

Name          : l
ModuleName    :
Module        : @{Name=}
CommandType   : Function
Definition    : Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending
ParameterSets : {@{Name=__AllParameterSets; IsDefault=False; Parameters=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `Get-Command` seems right, aliased as `gcm`
- Just pipe it to `Select-Object *` aliased as `select *`

E.g., in `$profile` I have a function that opens total commander from pwd (it silently kills the existing instance first)

```
function start-totalCommanderhere {
    $here = (Get-Location).path
    kill -n TOTALCMD64 -ErrorAction Ignore
    start "c:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD64.EXE" $here
}
Set-Alias tc start-totalCommanderhere
```

- Here is all the info about the function — it however does not tell you directly that it is a function, you would need to query its proper name not alias to get that information from `CommandType` attribute. (than it would be same as `type` in bash which tells you `hello_world is a function` in case it is one)

```
▶ gcm tc | select *

HelpUri             :
ResolvedCommandName : start-totalCommanderhere
DisplayName         : tc -> start-totalCommanderhere
ReferencedCommand   : start-totalCommanderhere
ResolvedCommand     : start-totalCommanderhere
Definition          : start-totalCommanderhere
Options             : None
Description         :
OutputType          : {}
Name                : tc
CommandType         : Alias
Source              :
Version             :
Visibility          : Public
ModuleName          :
Module              :
RemotingCapability  : PowerShell
Parameters          : {}
ParameterSets       :
```

- `gcm <module_name> | select *` gives you the path if you ask for a `CommandType` which is `Application`

```
▶ gcm ping | select *

HelpUri            :
FileVersionInfo    : File:             C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE
                     InternalName:     ping.exe
                     OriginalFilename: ping.exe.mui
                     FileVersion:      10.0.19041.320 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
                     FileDescription:  TCP/IP Ping Command
                     Product:          Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
                     ProductVersion:   10.0.19041.320
                     Debug:            False
                     Patched:          False
                     PreRelease:       False
                     PrivateBuild:     False
                     SpecialBuild:     False
                     Language:         English (United States)

Path               : C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE
Extension          : .EXE
Definition         : C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE
Source             : C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE
Version            : 10.0.19041.1
Visibility         : Public
OutputType         : {System.String}
Name               : PING.EXE
CommandType        : Application
ModuleName         :
Module             :
RemotingCapability : PowerShell
Parameters         :
ParameterSets      :
```

- But with `gcm` you do not get paths for imported modules — for that you need to use `Get-Module | Select-Object Name, Path` aliased as `gmo | select name,path`

```
▶ gmo | select name, path

Name                            Path
----                            ----
assign-vault-keys-to-env-vars   C:\Users\Admin\Documents\workspace\work.log\kb\powershell\assign-vault-keys-to-env-vars.ps1
CimCmdlets                      C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.dll
decode-base64                   C:\Users\Admin\Documents\workspace\work.log\kb\powershell\decode-base64.ps1
DnsClient                       C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\DnsClient.psd1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this with Shell, in addition to PowerShell's `Get-Command`, there's `where.exe`:

```
PS C:\> where.exe notepad
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

The command just looks for a file with the specified name through the path:

```
PS C:\> where.exe readme.*
C:\Python31\README.txt
C:\Program Files (x86)\wget\README
C:\Program Files (x86)\SysinternalsSuite\readme.txt
```

Note that when calling this command from PowerShell, you must call it as `where.exe` because `Where-Object` is aliased to `where`.